# How do I access drush commands specific to CiviCRM?

Tags: drupal, installation, drupal-8, scheduled-job, drush

I have installed CiviCRM 5.31 on Drupal 8 with the following set of commands according to the official [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies) and [CiviCRM](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/) documentation:

```
cd /var/www
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:8.9.8 d8.example.org
cd d8.example.org
composer require drush/drush
vendor/bin/drush site:install
composer config extra.enable-patching true
composer require civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin:'~1.1'
composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.31'
# now enable CiviCRM module in web UI
```

Now I want to setup scheduled jobs as [outlined](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#drush) in CiviCRM's documentation. Running `vendor/bin/drush civicrm-api`, however, leads to the following error:

```
Command "civicrm-api" is not defined.
```

<del>As of November 2020, [cv](https://github.com/civicrm/cv) is untested for Drupal 8</del>, so I would like to use `drush`. What's the "official" way to do this?

---

Software versions

- PHP 7.3.24
- mysql 8.0.22
- Composer 2.0.6
- Drush Commandline Tool 10.3.5
- Drupal 8.9.8
- CiviCRM 5.31.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The readme for cv needs updating. It's now tested pretty well with drupal 8. I would use cv instead.

See also https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/76